Showing a persistent vertical list of buffers?
There's an issue on Neotree's repo requesting it to show every buffer. Right now for me it only shows buffers that have been edited. I want a persistent window of file buffers to be shown regardless of their statuses. I have keymappings for :bnext and :bprev, and a list allows me to see the buffer's position relative to other buffers.

In the area of telescope and bufferline your demand is not so popular anymore.
Here are some candidates that could be of interest:

bufexplorer
bufstop
buffer_manager.nvim

I'm using vim-clap for that purpose (an alternative to Telescope).
But if you use wilder.nvim to get a nice completion menu in the command line, you can easily switch your buffers using the :b command that will provide you completion for your buffers.

